# Variable not Initialized - Although I am?

Tags: java, arrays, string, variables

**Answered**

Mike suggested I added some code to the

```
default:
break;
```

part of the switch. I added an exception to it, and there is no need to change anything else. The code now runs successfully. **Thanks guys!**

---

**EDITED FOR READABILITY:**

Error: "Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
The local variable messages may not have been initialized    TweetFragment.java    /Offline Twitter/src/com/deadpixels/offline/twitter    line 78    Java Problem"

for line:

```
int handleStartsAt = messages[i].indexOf('@');
```

And the same error happens twice on line 80, that being:

```
ph = messages[i].substring(handleStartsAt, messages[i].length());
```

As far as your questions, the

```
default:
break;
```

line was added as the int tweet type should only be either 0, 1, or 2. The function is called within a controlled environment and that way I am sure the call will not return an exception.

**END OF EDIT.**

I am trying to create a method to return a String array. This String array has a size that will change depending on the message type that is passed to the method as a parameter. I am having some issues getting this done, as apparently I am not initializing my variable; although, I think I am.

The variable I am having issues with is the "messages" array.

Bear in mind that I cannot declare the following:

```
String [] messages = new String [arrayLength];
```

As at this point in the call I do not know the length of the array. And I cannot do this:

```
String [] messages = null;
```

since after this, I will run into a runtime error, despite of not getting alerts at compile time.

Also, just to clarify, I would have though that:

```
messages = OfflineTwitter.mentions;
```

the above line would be initializing the variable, "OfflineTwitter.mentions" is an array, only stored in a different class.

Here is the code snippet.

```
public String[] getHandles (int tweetType) {

    int arrayLength = 0;
    String [] handles;
    String [] messages;

    switch (tweetType) {
    case 0:
        arrayLength = OfflineTwitter.mentions.length;
        messages = OfflineTwitter.mentions;
        break;
    case 1:
        arrayLength = OfflineTwitter.directMessages.length;
        messages = OfflineTwitter.directMessages;
        break;
    case 2:
        arrayLength = OfflineTwitter.allTweets.length;
        messages = OfflineTwitter.allTweets;
    default:
        break;
    }

    handles = new String [arrayLength];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        int handleStartsAt = messages[i].indexOf('@');
        String ph = "";
        ph = messages[i].substring(handleStartsAt, messages[i].length());
        int handleEndsAt = ph.indexOf(":");
        String sender = ph.substring(0, handleEndsAt);
        handles[i] = sender;
    }

    return handles;
}
```

Comment: Hint: **The compiler isn't lying**. In any case, post the *exact* error message, including line number.

Comment: You didn't say which error, or where it occurs.  Please post a COMPLETE stack trace and indicate in your code where the exception is thrown.

Comment: @JimGarrison It's a compiler error, no stack-trace ;-)

Comment: What line is giving you the error?

Comment: Then post the error message and indicate the line in your code.

Comment: I added some code bits at the beginning and some explanations.

Comment: @daniel_c05, The `default: break;` whether explicitly present or not, is a code-path along which the array is not initialized.  The compiler does not attempt to distinguish which code-paths are reachable and which are not by looking at input values -- it assumes that any input of that type can reach the function.  That code-paths mere existence is enough to cause this error.  If it is truly unreachable, then change it to `default: throw new AssertionError("unreachable");` and recompiler.  Your error messages will go away.

Comment: @MikeSamuel thanks man! That does make a lot of sense. I did add some more code to the default part of the switch and that fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `tweetType < 0 || tweetType > 2` then

```
default:
    break;
```

is reached which does not assign a value to `messages`.

You need to assign a value in the `default` branch, or `throw` an exception, or `return` so that the array is initialized at first use.

Perhaps change that to

```
default:
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid tweet type : " + tweetType);
```

or ideally change `tweetType` to be an `enum` so that you can cover all cases exhaustively.

```
enum TweetType {
  MENTIONS,
  DIRECT_MESSAGES,
  ALL_MESSAGES,
  ;
}
```

and change `int tweetType` to `TweetType tweetType`.

Comment: That can't be the problem in this case though, since `arrayLength` will be zero and the loop won't run.

Comment: @jnylen It's a *compiler error*, not an Exception. The compiler is only so smart, but it enforces the static analysis rules that can be trivially done. (Actually, I am pretty sure this is well-defined in the JLS as a requirement.)

Comment: So set the array to `null` at first.  He says that this results in a runtime error.

Comment: @jnylen, The compiler doesn't attempt to prove that.

Comment: @jnylen Which is not the "current" issue, albeit the question is poorly worded. Assigning `null` (first) will eliminate the compiler error .. but a bug could induce a runtime Exception.

Comment: @pst, What do you mean about the "current" issue?  This question is titled "Variable not Initialized - Although I am?" and the "Although I am" part is clearly false.

Comment: I agree that these are good ways to improve the quality of code and get rid of the compilation errors, but it seems like there are more problems waiting after that.

Comment: @MikeSamuel The "previous" issue, as discussed in the post, is an Exception when the variable was assigned `null` all the time ;-)

Answer (score -1):

There's a problem in the logic of your `for` loop.  Setting the array to `null` will work fine to get around the compilation error.  Post the resulting error stacktrace for more help.