# The local variable may not be initialized

Tags: java, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Variable not Initialized - Although I am?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148387/variable-not-initialized-although-i-am)

I'm fairly new to programming so i wanted to try and make a simple calculator that was not specific to one symbol like +. Anyway, i'm not quite sure why this isn't working because as far as i know i've done everything right.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calculator2 {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner tom = new Scanner(System.in);
        double fnum, snum, answer;
        int symbol;


        System.out.println("Enter First Number");
        fnum = tom.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter Comand, 1 = add, 2 = subtract, 3 = divide, 4 = multiply");
        symbol = (int)tom.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter Second Number");
        snum = tom.nextDouble();

        switch (symbol){

        case 1:         
            answer = fnum + snum;

        case 2:         
            answer = fnum - snum;

        case 3:         
            answer = fnum / snum;

        case 4:         
            answer = fnum * snum;       
        }

        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: Tag the question with the *language* you are using. `variables` and `local` could relate to any language and are so generic that they won't have many followers. Also, don't use tabs in code on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your did not initialize `answer` variable, and your `switch` statement is missing a `default` case to assign it. Java compiler reasons that if `symbol` is *not* `1..4`, then `answer` would remain uninitialized at the time that you pass it to `println`.

You can either set `answer` to some initial value at the point of declaration, or add a `default` case to the `switch`.

Comment: This is wrong, the default case is optional.

Comment: @ChrisMcCabe I added some clarifications. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Either assign a default value to it when declaring the variable (initialize it), or provide a default case to the switch:

Option 1:

```
double answer = 0;
```

Option 2:

```
switch(symbol) {
    case 1:
        ...
    default:
        answer = 0;
}
```

Note that you have a serious bug in your code: each block of code for your cases should end with a `break;`, ie

```
switch(symbol) {
case 1:
    answer = fnum + sum;
    break;
etc
default:
    answer = 0;
}
```

Otherwise all code for following cases is executed too. A switch case is like a goto.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give fnum, snum, answer an symbol a value when you declare them or java cannot guarantee it has a value to work with in further calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Or you add a default clause for your switch statement or you need to initialize your *answer* variable.

Also, your code is probably buggy, because of 'switch fall through'. When a condition in a case statement is met, the following case statements will also be executed until there is a break (or return) statement.

If I were in your situation I would code something like:

```
double fnum = 0, snum = 0, answer 0;
int symbol = 0

...

switch (symbol){

    case 1: 

        answer = fnum + snum; break;

    case 2:

        answer = fnum - snum; break;

    case 3:

        answer = fnum / snum; break;

    case 4:

        answer = fnum * snum; break;
    default:

    }
```